# storing and reusing conditional expression

Tags: c#

I need to evaluate same conditional expression multiple times in code.
What is the best way to store and reevaluate the conditional expressions in C#

eg. I want to remove the duplication of conditional expression given in while and if without using additional function call

```
while(!int.tryparse(num) || num <= 0 || num > 2000)
{
    num = console.ReadLine();

    if(!int.tryparse(num) || num <= 0 || num > 2000)
    {
        console.write("There is an error in the input value");
    }
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to create a function with the conditional statements, then call the function every time you need to?

Comment: The best way is to use a call to a method-local lambda or function. It might help if you explain why you do not want to use an additional function call; please edit your question.

Comment: What type is `num`? Is it a string or an int?

Comment: `int.tryparse(num)` is not legal syntax

Comment: Where did `num` get initialized before the `while`?

Comment: I have many functions using the similar blocks but with different conditions. I don't want to create so many function for each condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but one handy way to get strongly-typed (and otherwise valid) input from the user is to write a method that takes in a `string` prompt (which asks the user for some input) and an optional `Func<int, bool>` argument that returns `true` if the `int` meets some criteria. We can also have an optional error message to display if the input is incorrect.

Here's a method that I've used in the past:

```
public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null, 
    string error = null)
{
    int result;
    bool invalidInput = false;

    do
    {
        if (invalidInput && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(error);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        Console.Write(prompt);
        invalidInput = true;
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) || 
             (validator != null && !validator.Invoke(result)));

    return result;
}
```

In use, it makes life really simple, because you never have to write the validation code again. Note that we can just write an in-line lambda expression for our validator argument:

```
int input = GetIntFromUser("Enter a number from 0 to 2000: ",
    x => x >= 0 && x < 2000, "Invalid number, try again.");
```

**Output**

[image]

Now, if we want to use the *exact same* validation over and over again (in different areas of code, outside of a loop), we can extract the above method call to a `Func<int>` and call it whenever we want:

```
Func<int> ZeroTo2000 = () => Temp.GetIntFromUser("Enter a number from 0 to 2000: ",
    x => x >= 0 && x < 2000, "Invalid number, try again.");

int input1 = ZeroTo2000();
int input2 = ZeroTo2000();
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract to a separate  method.

```
public bool IsValid(string input)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(input, out var result)) return false;
    return (result > 0 && result <= 2000);
}
```

Then you can use it like this (your original code had problems which I fixed):

```
while (true)
{
    num = Console.ReadLine();
    if (IsValid(num)) break;
    Console.WriteLine("There is an error in the input value");
}
```

Comment: I think your first code block is missing a bool return type, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both the code for reading the input and the code that validates the input. Also, if you prefer to encapsulate the validation code within the same method, you can use delegates. See below.

```
Func<string,bool> InputIsInvalid = (stringNum) => 
{ 
  int intNum; 
  return !int.TryParse(stringNum, out intNum) || intNum <= 0 || intNum > 2000; 
};

while(InputIsInvalid(Console.ReadLine()))
{
   Console.WriteLine("There is an error in the input value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a middle exit loop with an infinite `for` and `break` to test only once:

```
string snum;
int num;

for (;;) {
    snum = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Int32.TryParse(snum, out num) && 0 <= num && num <= 2000)
        break;

    Console.Write("There is an error in the input value");
}
```